# What event of WebBrowser is triggered when File Download (Open/Save/Cancel) Dialog appears?

Tags: c#, browser, download, windows, navigatetourl

I am currently using C# and webbrowser on a windows application to navigate to a site that will automatically trigger a file download dialog or Open/Save/Cancel Dialog. The problem is I want to **close the form window** that is currently running the web navigation **after the file download dialog appears**. So I am here asking is there an event that will be triggered on file download occasion so that i can put:

```
this.close()
```

on that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to DWebBrowserEvents2.FileDownload event.

[Check it out...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881729/display-custom-dialog-when-file-downloaded)